# SharePoint 2013 - ScrollTop not working properly on second click

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

This is the weirdest thing.  I have the following javascript code, which causes my page to scroll to a specific location on click...

```
$('.whyattend').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#s4-workspace').animate({ scrollTop: $('#whyattend').offset().top });
});
```

When I click the first time it scrolls to my location, but when I click the same link a second time, it scrolls all the way back to the top of the page.  It's doing this toggle thing.  How can I avoid that so that it stays at the right page location the first click, second click, etc... until I decide to click a completely different link?

Thanks!

Comment: add a ``console.log( $('#whyattend').offset().top)`` and check if thats correct

Comment: That value changes on every click.  First and third click are 2675.897 and second and fourth click are 0.0

Comment: So .. ``scrollTop:0`` will...scroll to the top of your page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I discovered my issue and a potential solution..Using **position()** In my case the offset is not relative to the ( #s4-workspace), but relative to a child element that has a fixed position.

```
$('#s4-workspace').animate({ scrollTop: $('#target').position().top }, 500);
```

My target is inside of child container main...

```
<div id="#s4-workspace">

    <div id="main">
       <a href="#target">scroll to target and stay there</a>
       //...
       <div id="target">scroll to this position</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

...and #main has a position:fixed property applied to it.

This was a good learning exercise in knowing when to apply offset() and when to apply position().

Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

It will be less weird if you do:

```
window.whyattendOffset=$('#whyattend').offset().top;
$('.whyattend').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#s4-workspace').animate({ scrollTop: window.whyattendOffset });
});
```

*disclaimer.. sticking it on the window context so it works, I do not know your other code*